# Generate warning for TODO and FIXME in Xcode with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, bash

I tried to generate warning in Xcode if there is any `TODO:` or `FIXME:` in my project using the follow bash script from [HERE](http://jeffreysambells.com/2013/01/31/generate-xcode-warnings-from-todo-comments):

```
TAGS="TODO:|FIXME:"
echo "searching ${SRCROOT} for ${TAGS}"
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" \) -print0 | xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($TAGS).*\$" | perl -p -e "s/($TAGS)/ warning: \$1/"
```

As I used CocoaPods, is it possible to search only with my project and it's testing but not in the Pods?

EDIT: Update sample code for .swift compatibility

```
TAGS="TODO:|FIXME:"
echo "searching ${SRCROOT} for ${TAGS}"
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" -or -name "*.swift" \) -print0 | xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($TAGS).*\$" | perl -p -e "s/($TAGS)/ warning: \$1/"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the line:

`find "${SRCROOT}"` ...

to include a forward slash and your project name after the ending curly brace.
For example, if your app was called SaxGuy, it would look like this:

`find "${SRCROOT}/SaxGuy"` ...